# Convert velocityX and velocityY to Angle

Tags: java, math, velocity, trigonometry, angle

In my application, I have a GestureListener with a fling method. This fling method returns an x velocity and y velocity, which is the speed of the finger moving in the x and y direction. The problem is, I want to know the angle in either radians or degrees of the fling. How could I achieve this?

Here is the method:

```
@Override
public boolean fling(float velocityX, float velocityY, int button) {
    return false;
}
```

All help is appreciated.

Comment: As for some reason my edit was rejected, can you please remove the velocity tag, as this is nothing to do with Apache Velocity...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the angle use the math function atan2. It returns the angle in the range -PI to PI

```
double velX = ?;
double velY = ?;
double angleRadians = Math.atan2(velY, velX); // Note Y comes first
```